# React useEffect Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, es6-promise

```js
import { handleResponse, handleError } from "./apiUtils";
const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;




export  function getAllNotes() {
  return  fetch(baseUrl + "/notes", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  
})
  .then(res =>res.json())
  .then(data=>console.log(data))
}
```

```js
export async function handleResponse(response) {
  if (response.ok) return response.json();
  if (response.status === 400) {
    // So, a server-side validation error occurred.
    // Server side validation returns a string error message, so parse as text instead of json.
    const error = await response.text();
    throw new Error(error);
  }
  throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
}

// In a real app, would likely call an error logging service.
export function handleError(error) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.error("API call failed. " + error);
  throw error;
}
```

I am trying to learn react functional components and get comfortable with React Hooks. I am importing a function from a Api.js page and running it inside useEffect. The function is supposed to hit my back end which retrieves data from mongo Atlas and sends it up to my front end to be mapped. The data is an array of 4 objects. I am unable to map it because when the component renders the test variable is undefined. I have struggled to understand this for a long time. This would be a huge help and please explain in a not so technical way I struggle understanding very technical terms. Thank you!

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {getAllNotes} from '../api/authorApi'

function CourseList(props) {
  const [test, setTest] =useState([])
  
  useEffect(()=>{
      getAllNotes().then(_test=> setTest(_test))
  }, []);
  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Author ID</th>
          <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {test.map(course => {
          return (
            <tr key={course.user_id}>hi
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: The problem is with the `getAllNotes` function, not with the code provided (most likely)

Comment: This code seems to be fine. Maybe something wrong inside getAllNotes ?

Comment: ` test variable is undefined` Well initially the value is an empty array, which is not undefined, then you set it with `_test` So the problem is there, the `_test` is not what you are expecting

Comment: this is the function being imported from another file:

export  function getAllNotes() {
  return  fetch(baseUrl + "/notes", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  
})
  .then(res =>res.json())
  .then(data=>console.log(data))
}

Comment: Please update your question with the additional code. Also, you should check `res.ok` of the fetch request to ensure the fetch was successful. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful

Comment: @DrewReese I just updated the code. I don't use stackoverflow often so I may have butchered how to properly update and insert code snippets. But the whole code for everything to run that function is there now. Any ideas? Nothing seems to be working. Remember that it returns an array of four objects so maybe I am not grabbing the data right? I really don't know...

Answer (score 1):

There is little change, you have to return a promise.

Sample code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';

const getNotes = () => {
  return new Promise (
    (resolve, reject) => 
   fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
   .then(data => resolve(data.json()))
   .catch(err => reject(err))
   )  
}

const ToDos = () => {
  const [toDos, setToDos] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes().then( data => setToDos(data))
  }, []);

  const renderData = () => toDos.map((toDo) => <li>title: { toDo.title } </li>)
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ul>
      {renderData()}
      </ul>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default ToDos;
```

In your case there is nothing returned from the function `getNotes` after completion of an API call, hence the `test` is undefined, as a result it breaks down to an error: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

working code snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-bwt89?file=/ToDoSample.jsx